# Set bootstrap switch component to 'checked' if mode is Dark

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, local-storage

I have a theme for my web App in my localStorage and I want to add the checked value to the Switch component if the mode is set to 'dark',or unchecked, if the mode is 'light'.
However, when I set the theme to 'dark' and refresh the page the switch turn automatically to unchecked, how can I fix that?
Below there is the code:

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import useTheme from '../custom/useTheme';

export default function Switch() {
  const[active,setActive] = useState(false);

  function handleTheme(){
    if(active === false){
      // Dark mode
      useTheme(true);
      setActive(true);

      localStorage.setItem('mode','dark');
    }else if(active === true){
      // Light mode
      useTheme(false);
      setActive(false);
      localStorage.setItem('mode','light');
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <div id='switchBox' className='form-check form-switch'>
      <input
      id="switch" 
      role="switch"
      // checked
      value={active}
      type="checkbox"
      onClick={()=> handleTheme()}
      className="form-check-input shadow-sm"
      />
      <label
      className='ms-1'
      htmlFor='switch'
      >Dark</label>
    </div>
  )
};
```

That's how it looks, the Dark theme is on, but the Switch is unchecked.

[image: Dark mode on, but Switch turn off]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using checked with a ternary operator, giving to it the True or False value in the case I want to...
That's the correct solution !

```
  <input
  id="switch" 
  role="switch"
  checked={localStorage.getItem('mode') === 'dark'?(true):(false)}
  value={active}
  type="checkbox"
  onClick={()=> handleTheme()}
  className="form-check-input shadow-sm"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `useEffect` hook with an empty array. This will trigger the logic inside once when the component is rendered. Inside you can retrieve the previously saved `mode` property and use it to set the current session state:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const isLight = localStorage.getItem('mode');
    if (isLight !== undefined) setActive(isLight);
}, [])
```

Comment: That doesn't reply to my question, I said: 'How can I fix that ' and not why the useState get lost during refresh... Please make a better answer.

Comment: Apologies, I have changed the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer mentions, state is stored in memory and is lost when you refresh the page. While your solution persists the theme state to localstorage you also need to **set the initial value of useState to the value stored in localstorage** in order to display the correct state after refresh. You can try something like this:

```
const[active, setActive] = useState(false)

// Get stored data from local storage if available on first render
useEffect(() => {
    // Get stored theme mode and set it in state manager
    const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem('mode')
    if(storedTheme) {
        setActive(storedTheme)
    }
}, [])
```

By passing an empty array as the second parameter to useEffect this will only run on the initial render.
For more information on useEffect, refer to the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: I think you didn't try your code 'cause it throw an error... Thank you as well

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated my answer